# How to use knockout mapping?

Tags: mvvm, mapping, knockout.js

I have applied bindings to the following view model

```
var groupDeleteViewModel = {
        group: { Id: ko.observable(), Name: ko.observable(), Members: ko.observableArray() },
        load: function (item) {
            debugger

        },
        remove: function (item) {
            groupDeleteViewModel.group.Id(item.Id());
            groupDeleteViewModel.group.Name(item.Name());
            groupDeleteViewModel.group.Members(item.Members());
            $("#groupDelete").show();
        },
        cancel: function () {
            $("#groupDelete").hide();
        }
    }
```

the remove function loads the view with the data that has been passed in *item* to the remove function.

```
<div id="groupDelete" class="pop-window filter-view">
    <h2>
        Delete Group
    </h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
            <td>
                <span data-bind="text:group.Name" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!--ko foreach: group.Members-->
        <tr>
            <th>
            </th>
            <td>
                <div data-bind="text:Name" class="grey-border">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!--/ko-->
    </table>
    <span class="centeralign">
        <input type="button" value="Delete" data-bind="click: remove" class="delete" />
        <input type="button" value="Cancel" data-bind="click: cancel" />
    </span>
</div>
```

I don't want to keep mapping each element of *item* to each element of *groupDeleteViewmodel.group*. I have done it at a lot of other places also in the code which has made the code really messy. I want to use the ko.mapping plugin to do the same thing.

Till now what I have tried is -

```
remove:function (item){
            var data = ko.mapping.toJS(item);
            ko.mapping.fromJS(data, groupDeleteViewModel.group);
            $("#groupDelete").show();
}
```

But this just does not work. i really don't know why. It should have worked ideally.
Can someone tell what is the right way of using ko.mapping in such a case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping plugin is looking for mapping data already present in `groupDeleteViewModel.group`, but it doesn't find it, because you didn't initialize `groupDeleteViewModel.group` using the mapping plugin.
So instead of initializing group like you did:

```
group: { Id: ko.observable(), Name: ko.observable(), Members: ko.observableArray() }
```

initialize it using the mapping plugin:

```
group: ko.mapping.fromJS({ Id: undefined, Name: undefined, Members: [] })
```

And this is me fiddling around with your code: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KXhem/13/)

Comment: You are the best! thanks a ton. I am just wondering if this is on their website also?

Comment: They say: `To create a view model via the mapping plugin, replace the creation of viewModel in the code above with the ko.mapping.fromJS function` and then: `Then, every time you receive new data from the server, you can update all the properties on viewModel in one step by calling the ko.mapping.fromJS function again`. They should probably be more explicit about it