# Not able to update model from a drop down using knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have this sample fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/pRteA/3/

The problem is that I have to show the 'Name' of the selected object in the drop down, in a span.
I am some how not able to do this for the SelectedUser object only. I feel that this has something to do with being linked to the select html tag.

However, i am still able to update the user.place object with no problem at all. I can not find any major difference in the way the 2 objects have been initialized.

Also, note that the sampleUsers list is actually coming from the server as an Ajax request every time, that is why I have used the method described here - [How to use knockout mapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699398/how-to-use-knockout-mapping)

JS:

```
    var sampleUsers = [{
        Name: 'a',
        Id: 1},
    {
        Name: 'b',
        Id: 2},
    {
        Name: 'c',
        Id: 3},
    {
        Name: 'd',
        Id: 4},
    {
        Name: 'e',
        Id: 5}];

    var userViewModel = {
        user: ko.mapping.fromJS({
            place: {
                country: undefined,
                continent: undefined
            },
            selectedUser: {
                Name: undefined,
                Id: undefined
            }

        }),
        userOptions: ko.mapping.fromJS([])

    }

ko.applyBindings(userViewModel);
ko.mapping.fromJS(sampleUsers, userViewModel.userOptions);​
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <select data-bind="options: userOptions,  optionsText: 'Name', value: user.selectedUser" class="grey-border">
    </select>
</div>Update

<div>
    <span>Country</span>
    <input type='text' data-bind="value:user.place.country" />
    <span data-bind='text:user.place.country'/>
</div>    

<div>
    <span>Continent</span>
    <input type='text' data-bind="value:user.place.continent" />
    <span data-bind='text:user.place.continent'/>
</div>
```

​

​

Answer (score 2):

You have several syntax errors, and are calling the mapping plugin improperly. I really think you might want to go through the [tutorials](http://learn.knockoutjs.com) again.

Here is your [fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pRteA/1/).

1. You modify the `userOptions` "array" after binding to it, meaning that at binding time it has no properties.
2. Then, after binding, the properties wont be subscirbed to, since you changed the structure of the object.
3. Your binding path for your span doesn't include the `()` needed to specify observables.
4. Your `selectedUser`'s properties declared inline, but still constructed through the mapping plugin. This is kind of wasteful. Minor gripe.

Comment: Tyrsius, I have updated the question - mainly because I am able to updated the rest of the fields quite easily in the same way described above. I am just not able to update the selected user object. Please help.

Comment: @TusharMathur I am a bit confused. Your code still contains all the errors I pointed out. Did you look at the fiddle I posted?

Comment: i did not find any "syntax" errors and it seems to be working for other objects in the viewmodel. It is possible that my understanding about knockout is not clear. I did see your fiddle too. The problem is that there, I am not having an option of updating the userOptions with different values. I am first setting the values and then binding it. Consider a case where - model is bound to a view  on page load, but shows data which is returned by an ajax request and the data can change also.

Comment: @TusharMathur You still have the option of updating the `userOptions` after binding. The situation you describe, showing data from an ajax request that can get updated, is a large part of the intention of Knockout. I don't know what else to put here though. Your original problem is fixed in the fiddle I posted, and I don't know what problem you are having now. You said you updated your question but none of your code changed. What *exactly* are you having trouble with?

Comment: I have updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pRteA/7/ you will observe that there are 2 objects which getting updated in 2 different ways. 1. place - using a text box, 2. selectedUser - using a select box. I need to understand why does updating the textbox update the span, and the select box not work at all ? I just need to know what is happening, I need to know what is it that I am doing wrong. I will take up your suggested solution that.

Comment: @TusharMathur If you open the javascript console you will see a binding error in your updated fiddle. Its failing because your binding is invalid. Please see error #3 in my answer. I don't know how else to tell you this. You have syntax errors. Nothing will work until they are fixed. Your new fiddle has *all the same problems* your first one did. You didn't fix any of them.